# c-lightning - Unknown Peer

Tags: lightning-network, testnet, core-lightning, channels

I'm trying to create a channel using c-lighting (testnet), but I keep getting an Unknown Peer error message.

- I used `cli/lightning-cli connect` which seemed to work fine.
- I used `cli/lightning-cli listnodes` and I see whole bunch of nodes.
- I used `cli/lightning-cli listpeers` and I see 1 peer.
- I used `cli/lightning-cli newaddr` to create a new address and funded it (3 confirms so far)
- I then try to use `cli/lightning-cli fundchannel` and I get an Unknown Peer message.

Answer (score 1):

Everything but the last Comand looks correct. There is no command `channel` in c-lightning. In order to open a channel you need to execute

```
cli/lightning-cli fundchannel id satoshi [feerate] [announce] [minconf]
  Fund channel with {id} using {satoshi} (or 'all') satoshis, at optional {feerate}. Only use outputs that have {minconf} confirmations.
```

The thing that beginners sometimes oversee is that before opening a channel with a node you need to peer with it first via the `connect` command like you did.

Comment: That was a mistake in the question, I did do fundchannel which is what gives the Unknown Peer error.  Any other tests I can do to try to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: can you post information from the logfile? (with loglevel debug?)

Comment: Got it working.  I was making a noob mistake in that I did not realise that the connect address and the fundchannel address had to be the same...

Comment: Yes, that is quite a common mistake. It could also have been that between the `connect` and the `fundchannel` command the connection was lost, e.g., the remote peer closed the connection. In that case you would have had a connection on which to open a channel, but when attempting to fund the channel it'd be already gone again,